# Android eclipse import project problems with encoding

Tags: android, eclipse, encoding

I import a project into Eclipse and the person that made it worked on apple computer.
So when I import I got project full of strange symbols instead of cyrillic letters

like this :

```
public static final String months[] = {"РЇРќР’РђР РЇ", "Р¤Р•Р’Р РђР›РЇ", "РњРђР РўРђ", "РђРџР Р•Р›РЇ", "РњРђРЇ", "Р�Р®РќРЇ", "Р�Р®Р›РЇ",...}
```

how can i make it look like normal?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge. The .java files read the same irrespective of the OS platform. Open your file in some editor, like wordpad etc.. It should show the same content. The symbols that are shown in your code, might because of the different language he used there which is not supportive in your OS.

Comment: I know for sure that we both use russian cyrillic language.

Comment: Do you have the ttf file that support that font?

Comment: It's .. a system font, this is about encoding. Like UTF-8, Windows-1251 (not sure about last number) etc

Answer (score 0):

It's because the encoding of the Java source files are wrong.

If you only want to change the encoding of the affected source files, select the file in Package Explorer and open its property window (right click->Properties *or* Alt-enter), and change the setting highlighted with arrows:
[image]

As to what the correct encoding should be, you'll need to ask the original programmer.

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties, then menu Project -> Clean... -> Clean all
2. right click on the project with errors -> Properties -> Android, make sure the Target is selected and is Android 3.0 or higher
3. check the build errors in the Problems view window and try to resolve them by yourselves